# How to get the base-url in node-red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm trying to expose a `JSON` as a `POST` request, where I'm trying to append the base-url with another value.

How could I get the base url value?

I tried using:

```
 var root = RED.settings.httpNodeRoot;
```

but then it returned only /, where as I'm expecting something like `http://localhost:1880`.

Is it possible to get the base url by using any node-red api?  Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly available, but you can assemble it from some of the available parts.

Have a look at the subscribe function in the [Wemo nodes](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/blob/master/hardware/wemo/WeMoNG.js#L86)

Basically you can get the port and the path from the RED.settings object, but the IP address very much depends on the machine you are running on. By default Node-RED binds to 0.0.0.0 (which is short hand for all available IP addresses).

If you are running on NodeJS newer than 0.12.x then you can get hold of the IP address of the default route which is normally a fair guess. For NodeJS 0.10.x you pretty much just have to guess.

```
var ipAddr;
//device.ip
var interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
var interfaceNames = Object.keys(interfaces);
for (var name in interfaceNames) {
  if (interfaceNames.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    var addrs = interfaces[interfaceNames[name]];
    for (var add in addrs) {
      if (addrs[add].netmask) {
        //node 0.12 or better
        if (!addrs[add].internal && addrs[add].family == 'IPv4') {
          if (ip.isEqual(ip.mask(addrs[add].address,addrs[add].netmask),ip.mask(device.ip,addrs[add].netmask))) {
            ipAddr = addrs[add].address;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        //node 0.10 not great but best we can do
        if (!addrs[add].internal && addrs[add].family == 'IPv4') {
          ipAddr = addrs[add].address;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (ipAddr) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

var callback_url = 'http://' + ipAddr + ':' + settings.uiPort;
if (settings.httpAdminRoot) {
  callback_url += settings.httpAdminRoot;
}
```

Looking at this code reminds me I have to add a fix for if HTTPS has been enabled....

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @hardillb. Well I haven't enabled `https` explicitly anywhere. I guess I have to do that within my **settings** as well?

Comment: Actually thinking about it some more, in most cases if https has been enabled it won't work because the WeMo devices will not trust the self signed certificates